# Explicitly set dependency TaskFlowAPI

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

Suppose I have a dag as follows:

```
def my_dag():

    @task
    def task_a():
        # Some code here
        return

    @task
    def task_b():
        # Some code here
        return

    task_a()
    task_b()

my_dag_instance = my_dag()
```

I would like to set `task_b` downstream from `task_a`. That is, I want `task_b` to execute only if `task_a` has executed successfully. How can I do so? Note that `task_a` does not return anything.

I tried `task_a >> task_b` right before the last line of my code (`my_dag_instance = my_dag()`) yet got an error along the lines of " TaskDecorator >> TaskDecorator is invalid operation". Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can do that, inside the dag context, and with task instance instead of task method reference:

```py
def my_dag():

    @task
    def task_a():
        # Some code here
        return

    @task
    def task_b():
        # Some code here
        return

    task_a() >> task_b()
    # or
    # A = task_a()
    # B = task_b()
    # A >> B

my_dag_instance = my_dag()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hussein! Let me try that out...

Comment: A tiny followup: 

What if `task_b` returns a value that I want to feed to a third task, say `task_c`? If I write:  
`task_a() >> task_c(task_b())`.

Would following dependence be respected `task_a >> task_b >> task_c`?

Comment: I don't think so, it will be `A >> C` and `B >> C` but A and B can be run in parallel, the best way is storing the task instances in variables, and use these variables to define the dependencies and provide the arguments

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought... Oh okay so in your above example, `A = task_a()`, A stores an instance of a task, NOT the return value of the function?

Comment: It doesn't store the value, but when you pass it as an argument to another task, airflow will replace this instance by the result of the task at run_time, this is one of the decorator features.

Comment: Oh wow! that's so cool, thanks Hussein!

Comment: Would this be the right way to express it. Again `task_a` no return value, `task_b` return value that `task_c` takes in.

``
A = task_a();
B = task_b();
task_c(B);

A >> B
``

Think dependency here would be A >> B >> task_c()

Comment: Yes, this should do the job!

Comment: Thanks Hussein you saved me! Trying to get my DAG to work here < 3